# Java try catch handling for multiple operations

Tags: java, try-catch

I have a block that does multiple method calls, say operations, in several other classes
Its built like this

Private String XYZ(args1, ags2..)

```
try { 
     some preprocessing (can throw exception)

     Opertaion 2 (can throw exception)

     Operation 3(can throw exception)

     Operation 4(can throw exception)
     } catch (exception e) {}
```

Operations 2, 3 and 4 may throw system exception but I need to ensure that  3 is implemented, even if 2 fails, and 4 is implemented
even if 3 fails

Can the code be written this way,.. I mean is it ideal/good programming?

```
try { 

     some preprocessing (can throw exception)

     try{

        Opertaion 2 

         } catch (...) {}  

     try {

        Operation 3

         } catch (...){}

     try {

         Operation 4

         } catch (...){}

     } catch (exception e){}
```

Comment: You do what you have to do.  In some cases it's sufficient to just set "progress" flags so you know how far you got.  In other cases you need separate try/catch ranges.  If you need to do 4 all the time in the above scenario, you need a range that ends prior to that to give you control if 1-3 errors out.

Comment: Do note that not every range needs a `catch`.  If you can do what you need with the `finally` clause there's no need to have a `catch` that does nothing but resignal the exception.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Catching Exception (as in the outer block) is not considered good practice - it is too coarse-grained. Otherwise, I think it's fine - there is no better way to do it in Java - except maybe this method is doing too much?

Comment: It would have been good for both readers and me if the down-vote came with an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To assure that all steps get a chance at executing you can do something like this.

```
try {
   do1();
}
finally {
    try {
        do2();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            do3();
        }
        finally {
            do4();
        }
    }
}
```